# SpringBoot: Persist nested JSON [using spring-boot-starter-data-rest + sql]

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have the following POST request:

```
{
    "name": "Peter",
    "lastName": "Smith", 
    "contact": {
        "phone":"12345679",
        "email": "peter@smith.com"
    }
}
```

And I would like to store that in a SQL DB as follow:

| id (int) | name (varchar) | lastName (varchar) | **contact (JSON)** |

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` so I only have the `UserRepository` and `User` Entity, which has an **Embedded** property **contact**

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;

    @Embedded
    @Column(name = "contact")
    private Contact contact;


 }
```

**Contact.java**

```
@Embeddable
public class Contact {
   private String phone;
   private String email;
}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    //     
}
```

If I make a POST request I get an error, because (guess) I'm not converting `Contact` to JSON.

I've already tried adding a `@Convert(converter = HashMapConverter.class)` but I get an error.

**HashMapConverter**

```
public class HashMapConverter implements AttributeConverter<Object, String> {

    private static final ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Object attribute) {
        try {
            return om.writeValueAsString(attribute);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
            //log.error("Error while transforming Object to a text datatable column as json string", ex);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        try {
            return om.readValue(dbData, Object.class);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            //log.error("IO exception while transforming json text column in Object property", ex);
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add the code of HashMapConverter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've got the same case for storing json field which is working perfectly. Please try :

Add dependency to pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Edit User class within :

```
@Entity
@TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class)
public class User {
    // other field here
    @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "json")
    private Contact contact;
    // getters, setters
}
```

Of course your database should support json type. For MariaDB for example you can refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json-data-type/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment. Unfortunatelly I've got this error:

`java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'phone' in 'field list'`. I guess it's still trying to find a column for the contact propreties

Comment: did you remove Embeddable and Embedded annotations? Contact class should be a pojo with only fields, getters and setters. If it still does not work try to add JsonProperty annotation above each declaration of phone and email fields

Comment: WORKS! That's was the problem: Embeddable/Embedded were still there. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an entity for `Contact` and then create a one to one relationship between the two. Check out this [example](https://attacomsian.com/blog/spring-data-jpa-one-to-one-mapping).

Comment: But this is not what I want to achieve. The SQL column is a JSON not a linked id